# c++ string.find() returnes length of the string

Tags: c++, string, tcp, find, telnet

Hi I am a little confused. My program uses TCP to transfer messages over network. Which is in my opinion irrelevant to my question.

```
std::stringstream tmp(buf);

            if (tmp.str().find("\r\n") == std::string::npos ) {
                std::cout << " doesnt have ending char" << std::endl;
            }else{
                std::cout << " position of ending char " << tmp.str().find("\r\n") << std::endl;
            }
```

when a message is read from client, it is pushed to stringstream. Then I am trying to find escape character, unfortunately string.find("\r\n") always return length of the string, even though "\r\n" is not contained in the buf.

I am using

> telnet

to test it, is it possible that this behavior is caused by the telnet?

This is output of my terminal:

```
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
200 LOGIN
asdadsgdgsd
```

and this is output from the program:

```
3001 PORT NUM 
sent message: asdadsgdgsd  END  
position of ending char 11
```

Comment: Now is an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger. Using your debugger will allow you to immediately check what `tmp.str()` returns, and solve your mystery. This is what a debugger is for. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string entered in the console then sent and received is

```
"asdadsgdgsd\r\n"
 012345678901_2_
```

So the value 11 is correct

Comment: so you are telling me that when I send anything using telnet, it is going to put "\r\n" at the end of the message? 
My entered message was just  "asdadsgdgsd" not "asdadsgdgsd **\r\n** "

Comment: The telnet input is finished by pressing `Enter` key. This will send the string terminated with `\r\n`. It's usual for console applications.